# collection.save() not persisting data to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm totally new to Nodejs, and I've been trying to update a field in my collection to no avail. Here's my code for pushing into an array on the model. 
[update array field in model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YFX0.png)

Then here's my schema. 
[course schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IavxQ.png)

Any reason why the changes are not saved to my database ? Thanks .

NB: I've tried using `markModified('enrolled_courses.completed_lesson')`, but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.route('/yourRoute').post((req, res) => {

  Schema.findOneAndUpdate({
    username: newName
  }, {
    $set: {
      enrolled_courses: [
        {
          key: newValue

        }
      ]
    }
  }, {
    upsert: true
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      res.send({message: "Successfully updated"});

    }
  })

});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying, but your code does not specify what object we are trying to edit in the enrolled_courses array, and also, it does not push into the completed_lessons array too. any more ideas please ?